# Assigning variables whilst in a context

Tags: assignment, contexts, user-interface

When working in a context, I would like all variable assignments to happen on symbols in the new context.

This doesn't normally happen. For example,

```
Quit[]
x=3
Begin@"mycontext`"
```

, then

```
x=4
?? x
```

produces a value of 4 for Global`x, rather than 3 for Global`x and 4 for mycontext`x as I would prefer in this case. This is because the Global meaning of x is used throughout (because the symbol x has appeared earlier in the Global context).

Is there any code I can add between these two blocks to make this happen? When x is referenced outside of an assignment, I would like x to be interpreted as normal.

I could indeed assign via mycontext`x=4, but what I actually want to do is to insert some context-starting/context-ending commands before/after a block of existing code, such that all variables inside the code will be treated as local, whilst avoiding the downsides of Block or Module. Namely, the downsides are that

1. I would have to record each variable name in the first argument
   of Block/Module,
2. I would no longer be able to evaluate the code line-by-line
   in the notebook.

Is this possible, and if so would there be any ugly side-effects?

Comment: Just prefix with a backtick.

Comment: Btw, there is no magic happening here if you understand how symbols are resolved. Read carefully the documentation of `$ContextPath`, `$Context`, `Begin` and `BeginPackage`. Your problem is that although `Begin` changes the `$Context`, it does not change the current `$ContextPath` which is why the global `x` is found first if it is already defined.

Comment: Even if the mycontext\` was included early on in $ContextPath, wouldn't the Global\`x still be used, as mycontext\`x was not defined when the expression "x=4" was interpreted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [`BeginPackage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BeginPackage)/[`Begin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Begin)? For example:

```
x=1;

BeginPackage["foo`"];
Begin["`Private`"];
Print[{x, Context[x]}];
End[];
EndPackage[]
```

> {x,foo`Private`}

Comment: Thanks, this appears to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can prefix symbols with a backtick in order to put them in the current context.

```
x = 1  (* global context *)
`x = 2  (* global context *)
Begin["xxx`"]
x = 5  (* global context (because exists) *)
`x = 6  (* current context *)
End[]
x  (* 5 *)
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about that notation. I'd like to not modify the internal code itself in this case, however.